# How to publish .app to app store?

Tags: ios, app-store, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm using Sencha Touch Tools to pack and codesign a webapp, but it outputs a .app file.

Doesn't it have to be an .ipa to upload to App Store?

Or can I just zip the .app file and publish it using Application Loader?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need ipa file for deployment, you can login to your appstore account, and create an ipa file with application bundle identifier. and then submit the file to app store

Comment: Where can I find Application Bundle Identifier? Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compress(zip) the .app then send through application loader
That's what I do.. And it works fine